# Unable to build the Asp.Net 5 web app on Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, asp.net-core, coreclr

I installed all the packages and tools from get.asp.net on new Mac.

When I create a new Web app and run `dnu build` command I get bellow error. Any thoughts how to fix it?

Logs: https://gist.github.com/prashantvc/73e1e9b5c71b26b2ba0e

*Update 7-Dec-2015*

`dnu restore` execute worked fine, output and project.json is here https://gist.github.com/prashantvc/9c0230f7fe058e80be2c

But, I am still not able to build the project :(

Comment: did you try dnu restore?

Comment: @JoeAudette yup, did not help :(

Comment: @Prashant the logs are the exact same after doing a `dnu restore`?

Comment: so you get errors when you run dnu restore? I think to help more I would need to see the project.json files for each project in your solution and maybe other files like nuget.config. It is not clear from the log if it is able to find the nuget feed or not

Comment: when did you install? there were some problems with rc1 and a few days ago get.asp.net was updated with rc1-update1 though it does not say anything about it on the page. depending on when you installed you may want to re-install

Comment: @JoeAudette Is rc1-update1 stable version?

Comment: @JoeAudette I believe, I am on the latest version  `dnx --version
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16202
 Type:         CoreClr
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Darwin
 OS Version:   10.11
 Runtime Id:   osx.10.11-x64`